# How can I make placing cursor on empty line behavior to place it after virtual indent?

Tags: tabs, rider

When I have an empty line between a few code lines and I place a cursor at this empty line, it's placed without any indentation in Rider. In VS it's placed after the virtual indentation same as the indentation of the surrounding code and this is the behavior I expect. Also, in Rider Home key doesn't move the cursor to the virtual indention.

Is there any way to have the behavior in Rider same as in VS?

Wrong:

[image: wrong]

Correct:

[image: correct]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in Rider that I'm familiar of is *Virtual Space* ([see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2022.2/Settings_Editor_General.html?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=RD&utm_content=2022.2)). Open *File | Settings | Editor | General* and set the highlighted property:
[image]

Now you can click anywhere in the editor and Rider will automatically create the necessary number of whitespaces.

But I understand that this is not 100% what you are looking for